# Windows environment variable %USERPROFILE% in File URI Scheme (three slashes)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, notepad++

In Notepad++ I have a link to a batch file using a "File URI Scheme with three slashes" convention as follows:

```
file:///C:/Users/john.doe/some_folder/test%20file.bat
```

When I double-click on it, the link works (i.e. the double-click runs the batch file).

I want to modify the File URI to incorporate `%USERPROFILE%` like so:

```
file:///%USERPROFILE%/some_folder/test%20file.bat
```

This doesn't work. Is there some character I can add or remove or escape to make it work?

---

**UPDATE:** since making this post, I've learned that Notepad++ doesn't expand Windows environment variables.

Comment: If the mechanism used by Notepad++, uses standard Windows environment variables, try using `%USERPROFILE:\=/%` instead of `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: @Compo - thanks for your suggestion. Not working unfortunately. Am happy to keep trying any other suggestions you might have. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do but don't you have your slashes backwards?

Comment: I haven't installed Notepad++. Is in documentation of Notepad++ written that it expands environment variables specified with `%VariableName%` like Windows command processor `cmd.exe`? It looks like that is not the case. I suggest to change the link (tool) configuration to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "%USERPROFILE%\some_folder\test file.bat"` to explicitly start Windows command processor for processing the batch file and then close itself.

Comment: @Mofi -- from what I've discovered after making my post, Notepad++ (also Joplin, the markdown editor I use), doesn't expand Windows environment variables.